# Why did the Philippines fall out of favor in the early 1970's for low budget film production aimed at the US?

Tags: production

The Philippines were a haven for budget film production by filmmakers such as Roger Corman in the late 1950s through to the early 1970's - what was the cause of the demise of a pretty steady pipeline of low budget actioners targeted at the US?

Comment: Could you write what reseach on Philippines history you made that didn't yeld any results? Marcos dictatorship, martial law and new constitution condemned by US congress _might_ be the reason.

Comment: I wasn't able to find anything on this - my assumption was the changing economics of film production in the US, but I don't know that there was such a substantive change early 1970's vs mid 1960s (when AIP was still going gangbusters with Filipino productions). It's unlike the 1990's period where access to DV camera's enabled a slew of low budget but notable movies